# Why can't Apache HttpClient 4.2 retrieve this page?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm trying to retrieve this page using Apache HttpClient:  http://quick-dish.tablespoon.com/

Unfortunately, when I try to do this, it just returns the following (as returned by JSoup, so probably it's really just returning the HTTP... string itself):

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Server: nginx/1.0.11, Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8, Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Jul 2012 15:30:40 GMT, Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie,Accept-Encoding, X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6, X-Pingback: http://quick-dish.tablespoon.com/xmlrpc.php, X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, Content-Encoding: gzip, X-Blz: lb1.blaze.io, Date: Mon, 02 Jul 2012 16:06:21 GMT, Content-Length: 11723, Connection: keep-alive]
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my code (note that I'm emulating the Google Bot as I've found that web servers tend to be better behaved that way):

```
URL sourceURL = new URL("http://quick-dish.tablespoon.com/");
HttpClient httpClient =  new ContentEncodingHttpClient();
httpClient.getParams().setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects", true);

final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(sourceURL.toURI());
httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");
httpget.setHeader("Accept", "text/html");
httpget.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");

final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
return Jsoup.parse(response.toString());
```

Needless to say, the page returns fine in my web browser.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of toString you need to get the response entity

```
// Get hold of the response entity
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Then you can get the contents of that

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String pageHTML = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
Jsoup.parse(response.toString());
```

Comment: Can you please add a little description to your answer, so that it will help some one who couldn't get it.